# How to migrate Inspection settings from Eclipse to Intellij?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In our company we have a strict list of Eclipse Error/Warning settings that must be used.  Compiling our changes with this list, no Errors/Warnings should exist before checking in.

These Errors/Warnings can be found in Eclipse under Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings. (Below is an example of some of the Eclipse settings, pls forgive the clipping at the bottom.)

I'm an IntelliJ user.  IntelliJ has a similar concept called "Inspections".  Inspection settings can be found under Settings -> Editor -> Inspections.

Does anyone know a way of migrating the Eclipse Errors/Warnings over the the closest possible match of IntelliJ inspection settings.  I can see that there is a way to export/import the IntelliJ settings, but can't see any such functionality in Eclipse.

Any help would be appreciated.

PLEASE NOTE: This question is NOT about migrating "Code Style" settings between Eclipse and IntelliJ.

[image]

Comment: Eclipse: _File > Export/Import...: General > Preferences_, select _Java Compiler Preferences_. If using project specific settings, the compiler preferences are stored in the project folder in `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` (all preferences, not only the preferences which are different from default).

Answer (score 3):

In **Eclipse** the ***Java Compiler Preferences*** can exported via ***File > Export...: General > Preferences***. Such an exported file only contains the settings that differ from the default setting.

For all *Java Compiler Preferences*, in a Java project in *Project > Properties: Java Compiler* make sure the checkbox ***Enable project specific settings*** is checked and use the project file **`.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`**.

I don't know if this files can be imported into IntelliJ. In my experience, there are **only correspondences *Inspections* for simple checks**. While comparing, I noticed that the *(potential) null pointer access* check of Eclipse finds problems that IntelliJ does not find. Surely there are also cases where Eclipse overlooks something or issues false warnings. [**Alternatively**, you could use the **Eclipse compiler that comes with IntelliJ**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/java-compiler.html#javac_eclipse). I haven't tried it yet, but with the [`-properties <file>`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_batch_compiler.htm) pointing to the `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file, it should be possible to see the problems found by Eclipse in IntelliJ. But remember that in IntelliJ the files are not compiled on saving but before execution.